# Why is my yarn install results in error to attach to certain github repository?

Tags: github, hadoop-yarn, virus

I just want to yarn install on my project and it gets following error.
Request failed "404 Not Found"

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.21
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
**error Error: https://codeload.github.com/hugomrdias/concat-stream/tar.gz/057bc7b5d6d8df26c8cf00a3f151b6721a0a8034: Request failed "404 Not Found"**
    at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:696:66)
    at new ResponseError (C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:802:124)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:66218:16)
    at Request.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:141751:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:693:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:535:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

And here's package.json file and it doesnt include such github repo

```
{
  "name": "@connectfinancial/staking-portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start:test": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true REACT_APP_CHAINID=31337 react-scripts start",
    "start:mainnet:test": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true REACT_APP_TEST=1 REACT_APP_CHAINID=42161 react-scripts start",
    "start:ropsten": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true REACT_APP_CHAINID=3 react-scripts start",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8196 REACT_APP_CHAINID=42161 react-scripts build",
    "build:ropsten": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8196 REACT_APP_CHAINID=3 react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.1.1",
    "@web3-react/core": "^8.0.23-beta.0",
    "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
    "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector": "^7.0.2-alpha.0",
    "@web3-react/walletlink-connector": "^6.2.13",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "ethers": "^5.6.4",
    "pretty-checkbox-react": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^7.4.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-select": "^5.3.1",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "swr": "^1.3.0",
    "web3-react-core": "npm:@web3-react/core@^6.0.9"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "comma-number": "^2.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "ethers-to-web3": "^0.1.6",
    "ipfs-deploy": "^8.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20"
  }
}
```

I think there's something added to my node module
How can I resolve this error?

I tried to install dependency for my project and got following error

Comment: Also started hitting this exact issue when running `yarn create next-app`. You figure out a solution?